# События c#

Tags: c#

Господа просветите пожалуйста по событиям. Читаю по Шилдту, то ли перевод такой. То ли я не могу разобраться.
Вот код который приводится в книге в качестве примера

```
using System;

delegate void MyEventHandler();

class MyEvent { 
  public event MyEventHandler SomeEvent;

  public void OnSomeEvent() { 
    if(SomeEvent != null) 
      SomeEvent(); 
  } 
}

class EventDemo { 
    static void Handler() { 
    Console.WriteLine("Event occurred"); 
  }

  static void Main() {  
    MyEvent evt = new MyEvent();

    evt.SomeEvent += Handler;

    evt.OnSomeEvent(); 
  } 
}
```

С кодом вроде все понятно. Но вот его дальнейшее описание вводит в заблуждение. Подскажите пожалуйста это трудности перевода или трудности в моем понимании темы

> Кроме того, в классе MyEvent
> объявляется метод OnSomeEvent (),
> вызываемый для сигнализации о запуске
> события. Это означает, что он
> вызывается, когда происходит событие.

Я не пойму метод вызывает событие или событие метод ? Я так понял, что метод OnSomeEvent () вызывает событие.

> В методе OnSomeEvent () вызывается
> обработчик событий с помощью  делегата
> SomeEvent.

Но имя делегата вроде MyEventHandler ? Или я что-то не понял ?

> Вызов метода OnSomeEvent () приводит к вызову всех событий, 
> зарегистрированных обработчиком.

Может быть к вызову всех зарегистрированных ОБРАБОТЧИКОВ для события ?

И еще вопросик совсем мелкий. Правильно ли я понял, что в методе OnSomeEvent() происходит все таким образом, что в методе сигнализируется само событие и автоматически (если подключен) вызывается его обработчик ?

Спасибо. Для меня очень важно получить ответы. Спасибо еще раз

Comment: Читайте, пожалуйста, внимательнее.

И еще, скажите пожалуйста. Вы понимаете что такое класс, а что такое экземпляр класса?

Comment: Да, конечно понимаю. Я читал достаточно внимательно, но все равно что-то завис

Comment: Хм, вроде все более чем ясно написано. Если не понимаете, подебажьте код

Comment: Ок. Если вас не затруднит, подскажите, например по первой цитате. Каким образом событие находящееся в теле метода OnSomeEvent() может вызвать сам этот метод ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Метод `OnSomeEvent` вызывает событие `SomeEvent`. Если Вы посмотрите на то, как реализовано большинство классов в .NET Framework, Вы увидите, что это общепринятый способ генерации событий.
2. Возможно, в книге не очень удачно сформулировано. Когда Вы объявляете делегат, Вы создаёте тип данных. Когда Вы объявляете событие, Вы создаёте член класса или интерфейса, который имеет этот тип. Соответственно, под выражением "делегат `SomeEvent`" подразумевается поле Вашего класса, которое создаётся при объявлении события. А тип этого поля - `MyEventHandler`.
3. Вы правильно понимаете, когда Вы обращаетесь к делегату так, как будто вызываете метод, вызываются все методы, подписанные на это событие.
4. Метод `OnSomeEvent` реализован таким образом, что если на событие никто не подписан, оно не инициируется. Если хоть кто-то подписан, оно инициируется, и тогда отработают все обработчики этого события.

Comment: Спасибо огромное  что ответили ! Очень помогли мне. А то остальные поленились даже прочитать вопрос, и сразу минус поставили. 
Еще раз ОГРОМНОЕ спасибо